# Is there a way for me to send session variable to another page with jQuery? (I am using Laravel btw)

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

After this function is successful and the else function becomes true. I want to redirect it to another page and send a session variable to that page.

```
    $(function(){
        $("#create_form").on('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                url:$(this).attr('action'),
                method:$(this).attr('method'),
                data:new FormData(this),
                processData:false,
                dataType:'json',
                contentType:false,
                beforeSend:function(){
                    $(document).find('span.error-text').text('');
                },
                success:function(data){
                    if(data.status == 0){
                        $.each(data.error, function(prefix, val){
                            $('span.'+prefix+'_error').text(val[0]);
                        });
                    } else {
                        $('#create_form')[0].reset();
                        $(location).attr('href', "{{ route('product.home') }}")
                        alert(data.msg);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Then, I want to grab that session variable 'message' like this on this new page. Then display it.

```
@if (session()->has('message'))
    <div id="session_message" class="m-10 text-center bg-red-100 border border-red-400 text-red-700 px-4 py-3 rounded relative" role="alert">
        <strong class="font-bold">Hey!</strong>
        <span class="block sm:inline">{{ session()->get('message') }}</span>
        <span class="absolute top-0 bottom-0 right-0 px-4 py-3">
        <a href="#" class="fa fa-times" id="close"></a>
    </div> 
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

When you submit the form with ajax request, you call a laravel function to store the data in db. After successfully saving the data you can set the message session and get that session in your blade file.